# Using Gamekit to Share Music Between Devices

Tags: ios, gamekit

Is there a way that I can develop an application that uses GameKit to share the music currently playing on another device?

The connection part using GameKit isn't the problem. It's the sharing music part that I'm having a problem with. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I realized that it is technically possible but because of copyright issues Apple won't allow it. In theory you can connect the 2 devices via GameKit and then get the MPMediaPropertyAssetURL for an audio item in the library, and open it with AV Foundation. You could use the AVAssetReader to read from the file and then stream them over the GameKit connection. So technically it's possible but legally might not be allowed! Hope this helps someone!